# Zero cross circuit exploded

Tags: zero-crossing

would like to get a feedback on a zero cross circuit as it does not work.

Circuit is based on [this](http://www.dextrel.net/diyzerocrosser.htm).
[image]
240V AC, 50 Hz

Expect that C2 is 50V.
R1,R2, R4 are SMD.

After connecting to mains and measuring voltage across R1, the track between J1(Ac+) and R1 exploded. R1 is alive.

Voltage on C2, R6 and U1 is 100 V

Is this circuit valid ?

Comment: If the failure occurred the moment you took the measurement, the original circuit is most likely not related to it. Did you use a voltmeter which was grounded, so that you've shorted J1 to ground?

Comment: *Is this circuit valid ?* Just like beer, all circuits are valid, some circuit do not work but that is something different. You mean, will this work ? I have my doubts about the connection between D3 and R2, it is not there in the original schematic. The original schematic looks OK to me.

Comment: The way the NPN is used is odd but I think it makes the LED light up on the down going slope of the waveform. Not sure that the LED will light up exactly at the zero crossing though.

Comment: No it is not valid. As Bimpelrekkie points out, you have short circuited one of the diodes in your bridge rectifier.

Comment: R1 draws 1 milliamp surge , but if V rating us not >600V , it may arc   start over. R6C1=10ms?  With Vbr reversed, it pulses when V drops at peak phase not ZCS, try simple passive bridge zener R to opto 1mA , 25% load

Comment: As others have mentioned, pin 4 of the bridge rectifier should not be connected to the DC ground, and the DC ground should not be connected to AC-. You're shorting out the diode between pins 2 and 4.

Comment: the only cause of exploding track is failure to observe breakdown voltages.  but failure of functional design, there are many other reasons.  go understand how it must work first from commercial designs

Comment: It is possible that you shorted something when you were measuring. How long was the circuit plugged//running before you touched it with mutlimeter?

Comment: Even with the diode shorted, the track should not have exploded: the series resistor is 220k per branch (440k in total), which limits the current to 0.5mA RMS. That circuit, without the wire that connects pin 4 of the bridge to D3 works perfectly. I have used that configuration too.

Answer (score 2):

I might be going on a side-track but may I suggest you to use this simpler zero crossing detector circuit:

[image: Zero cross detector]

This is the output that you will get:

[image: Output]

Blue curve is 220 VAC and yellow trace is the output at ZCD_OUTPUT.

Comment: not very sharp pulse but can be improved if a spec was given for pulse width before and after true 0 V which affects performance on application.

Comment: Since OP mentioned that he's using SMD components, it might be worth noting that the 300k resistor in this design should be rated for higher voltages than OP's design reference (which drops the mains voltage over two 220k resistors).

Comment: @whiskeyjack - Can you described how you arrived at the 300k resistor value?